MSBuild fails when referencing sys tables in a different database
SQL Server 2019.  We have a purchased application and can't add any code to that database (let's call it vendor).  We have a view in another database (call it xyz) that is getting data from the sys tables in the vendor database.
SELECT * FROM vendor.sys.objects

This code works fine, but MSBuild fails for database xyz on this view with an unresolved reference error.  I know you can add a reference to master in the database project, but that will be a reference to master in the xyz database, not the vendor database.
Is there a way to resolve this reference error?  Maybe some way to get the master tables into the vendor dacpac?

Can you import the vendor database to a database project and add the master database reference to the project there and then build that dacpac and reference that from the xyz project? Seems like logically that should work but I haven't tested it

@testing-for-ya I like the synonym idea, will give that a try.

@MartinSmith I tried that and it didn't work.  Good thought though.  :)

Add a new SQL Cmd variable called "VendorSys" and a database reference to "master". Have the default value of "VendorSys" set to the value "master" - I've just tested that far and a view with definition SELECT * FROM [$(VendorSys)].sys.objects builds without errors. Then when you publish you can hopefully set VendorSys to its desired final value of "vendor"

@MartinSmith Actually, I take it back.  I'm not sure what I did the first time, but I just tried again adding a reference to master in the vendor database and it worked!  Thanks very much!!

As Martin Smith mentioned in the comments, the solution was to add a reference to master in the Vendor database project.  Now the build works.  Thanks Martin!
